# Problems Creating my own Database in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

recently I decided to make my own database in php The reason is because I'm making a mini game online and I need to send some information more fast as possible (I Know it is not the best way to do that since I use web-pages.), So I noticed If I query a web-page (that has the php file) and then query a database, it takes me 1 seconds to 1.3 seconds which is a lot to me, So IF I just query a web-page it usually takes me 0.5 seconds so that is perfect to my purpose.

So What I need to do is save a multi array in the file 'db.txt' and make some checks for example if there is a value where the id is equal to 1 it should just change the array where the id is equal to 1 if there isn't a value where the id is equal to 1, so add it and the next time just modify.

This is what I did so far:

```
<?php

$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$positionX = $_REQUEST['positionX'];
$positionY = $_REQUEST['positionY'];

$infoDB = fopen("db.txt", "a+");
$conteudo = fread($infoDB, 4096);

$obj = json_decode($conteudo, true);

if($conteudo == ''){
    $table = json_encode(array(
    array('id' => $id, 'positionX' => "$positionX", 'positionY' => "$positionY", 'hp' => 100, 'hpmax' =>100, 'hit' => 0, 'mp' => 0, 'mpmax' => 0)
    ));
    $infoDB = fopen("db.txt", "a+t");
    fwrite($infoDB,$table);
    echo 'Writing first time ...';

}else{

    $infoDB = fopen("db.txt", "a+");
    $conteudo = fread($infoDB, 4096);
    $array = json_decode($conteudo, true);

    array_walk($array, "busca", $id);
}


    function busca($valor, $chave, $it) {
        if($valor['id']==$it){
            $valor['positionX'] = $GLOBALS["positionX"];
            $valor['positionY'] = $GLOBALS["positionY"];
            $table = json_encode(array($valor));

            $infoDB = fopen("db.txt", "w+");
            fwrite($infoDB,$table);
            echo $valor['id']." / ".$valor['positionX']." [".$valor['positionY']."]";
            echo 'rewriting...';

            }else{
                $id = $GLOBALS["id"];
                $positionX = $GLOBALS["positionX"];
                $positionY = $GLOBALS["positionY"];
                $arr = array('id' => $id, 'positionX' => "$positionX", 'positionY' => "$positionY", 'hp' => 100, 'hpmax' =>100, 'hit' => 0, 'mp' => 0, 'mpmax' => 0);
                $valor[] = $arr;
                $table = json_encode(array($valor));
                $infoDB = fopen("db.txt", "w+");
                fwrite($infoDB,$table);
                echo 'Adding One more. '.$valor['id']." e ".$id;
                }
                return;
    }

fclose($infoDB);
?>
```

I used the json_encode to save the array in the database.txt

> This is how **I believe** My script work.
>
> So first It gets the id, positionX and positionY, I open the db.txt
>   and then I decode it to array, I check if the db($conteudo) was empty
>   or not if so It write the first array if not It should check if there
>   is a value where id is equal a ($id = $_REQUEST['id'];) But there is a
>   bug in somewhere that make it just check the first value/array that was
>   saved on the db.txt I used a array_walk to try to do that But that is
>   the first time I used a array_walk so I don't know if I'm making it
>   right or wrong. If there is a better way to do what I want to do
>   please guys help me!! D:

Comment: Are you... seriously using a plain text file to store data? And use that as a JSON? I.. this.. wow. You need an actual database. A MySQL database.

Comment: Use a database. What you trying to do will break your neck some day :)

Comment: Hmmm... Although This is just a Test to see how it works, I'm still looking for a better way to make my own db :)

Comment: Use a database; if you're spending 1.5s waiting for data from a database, something is seriously wrong. Find out why it takes so long first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumtions about the speed of database-queries sound verry vague to me. Usually a latency as you describe it happens when the database is not on the same machine as the webserver, not in the same compute center and hast to make a connection via internet.

Usually the I/O speed heirachy looks something like this (beginning with the fastest)

- Memcache on same machine
- Memcache in local network
- Database on same machine
- Database in local network
- File System of your machine
- File System in local network

So if you really need to cache some basic key => value data and retrieve it at the speed of light, store it in memcache (i recommend the php memcached package). Memcache is simillar to what you want to build, but it is already finished, so you can go on work on your game.

Comment: Yeah Actually the database is not on the same server as the php files are... Maybe that is the reason that I'm getting so much lag, and that php memcached package thing sounds like that could be another solution to me... Thx i'll see it. o/